# Firestore - Creating multiple documents at once using Int value from querySnaphot

Tags: swift, firebase, foreach, google-cloud-firestore

At the moment I've got it so that when the user clicks on a button, all of the documents in the FirstCollection are then copied to a collection called SecondCollection, which works well!

What I'd like to do now is use the Int value from the field (numberValue) in all of the documents from the newly created collection called SecondCollection. Then use these values to create multiple documents in the subcollection called "SecondSubCollection" of the document.

So for example, say if the numberValue is 3 in one document, I'd like to perform a batch request and create 3 documents under the subcollection called "SecondSubCollection" of the document. Then do that for all of the documents in the SecondCollection with one request.

Please see the code below of what I have got so far. At the moment when I press on the button, it only creates one document in each of the subcollections, which isn't working the way I want to. I'd like to make it create multiple documents (if the numberValue is 3 in the document, it should be creating 3 documents in the subcollection of the document).

Hope this makes more sense! Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

**Code**

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userRef = db.collection("Users").document(user!)

    userRef.collection("SecondCollection").document(firstID).setData(["name" : "name"]) {
        error in

        if let error = error {
            print("Error adding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Document added with ID")
        }
    }

    let firstRef = userRef.collection("FirstCollection")

    firstRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let numberValue = data["numberValue"] as? Int ?? Int()
                    let batch = self.db.batch()
                    let docset = querySnapshot

                    let integerArray = [Int](1...numberValue)

                    let secondID = UUID().uuidString

                    let secondRef = userRef.collection("SecondCollection").document(secondID)

                    docset?.documents.forEach {_ in batch.setData(["name" : name, "numberValue" : numberValue], forDocument: secondRef)}

                    \\ the code that isn't working properly at the moment
                    let secondSubRef = secondRef.collection("SecondSubCollection").document()
                    docset?.documents.forEach {integerArray in batch.setData(["value" : Int], forDocument: secondSubRef)}


                    batch.commit(completion: { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("\(error)")
                        } else {
                            print("success")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What it's doing at the moment**

1. **FirstCollection**:

   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 3.
   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 2.
2. **SecondCollection**:

   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 3.
     - **SecondSubCollection**.

       - documentID.

         - value: 1.
   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 2.
     - **SecondSubCollection**.

       - documentID.

         - value: 1.

**What I'd like to do**

1. **FirstCollection**:

   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 3.
   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 2.
2. **SecondCollection**:

   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 3.
     - **SecondSubCollection**.

       - documentID.

         - value: 1.
       - documentID.

         - value: 2.
       - documentID.

         - value: 3.
   - documentID.

     - name: name.
     - numberValue: 2.
     - **SecondSubCollection**.

       - documentID.

         - value: 1.
       - documentID.

         - value: 2.

Comment: The question is unclear; can you update the question to indicate what part of the code you're having difficulty with? What's not working? Can you clarify what *use that array to create multiple documents* means? Remember, you know your project, we don't so you have to be pretty specific when describing the issue. Please review the following guide on asking questions: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks very much for the feedback. Please see the revised changes. Hopefully it all makes sense now. I'd be more than grateful if you could help me out with it, thanks!!

Comment: Without digging too deep the first thing that jumps out at me is you are coding top-down which doesn't work well for Firebase. Calls are asynchronous and attempting to access snapshots and data outside the closure can give intermittent results. This line *firstRef.getDocuments* may actually be called before SecondCollection can have name:name written. It may not be a big issue in this case but it's something to be aware of and write your code accordingly.

Comment: The other thing is that it appears the code that writes SecondSubCollection is overwriting the document node name so you only ever get one node. Check the secondSubRef var. (I may be wrong, if so, let me know and I will remove this comment)

Comment: Hi Jay, through your help I've found the solution, please see my answer if your interested... Thanks once again for the help, its greatly appreciated!! 

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working (simplified) solution: (Many thanks Jay for the huge help!)

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userRef = db.collection("Users").document(user!)

    let array = [1, 2, 3]

    array.forEach { number in

        let batch = self.db.batch()

        let docRef = userRef.collection("FirstCollection").document()

        batch.setData(["numberValue" : number], forDocument: docRef)

    }

    batch.commit(completion: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error)")
        } else {
            print("success")
        }
    })
}
```